# How to get the following output in most efficient way?

Tags: java, data-structures

Read a file of this format:

```
japan
usa
japan
russia
usa
japan
japan
australia
```

Print the output in the following format:

```
<country> : <count>
```

So for above file output would be:

```
japan : 4
usa : 2
australia : 1
russia : 1
```

Note that since australia and russia both have count as 1, the name are sorted, 'a' before 'r'. Do it in the most efficient way.

Here is what I tried:

```
Read the entire file and insert into a HashMap.
We will have pairs like <japan, 4> in there.
Now read the HashMap and insert in another TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>
Iterate over TreeiMap using a Comparator, which will iterate in reverse-sorted order.
Sort value (which will be a List<String>) and print the result.
```

Comment: The most efficient way would be to code it first. Seriously, please show your attempt and ask a real answerable question, not a homework dump.

Comment: This is not a homework. it was asked in the Amazon online test. Me and couple of my friends did solve it but none of us got selected. Thats why asking.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Just an observation that "Do it in the most efficient way" isn't a very clear requirement - most efficient in CPU, memory...?  And the 'best' solution in practice might depend on the size of data, number of duplicates etc.

Comment: You should have a look at [Tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 2):

this can be done in **O(n*S)** (n is the number of input strings,S is the biggest string size ) I'll give you a general algorithm,in pseudo code, the Java will be a bit messy...

```
arr <- HashSet<String>[NumberOfElements]
map <- HashMap<String,int>
for each country:
   if country in map.keySet():
        count <- map.get(country)
        arr[count].del(country)
        map.delete(country)
        count <- count + 1
   else:
        count <- 1
   arr[count].add(country)  
   map.put(country,count)
for i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--:
   sorted <- radixSort(arr[i])
   for each country in sorted:
      print country, i
```

arr here is a "histogram", since for every iteration the 'size' is increased by at-most 1, we use it to store the data.

**complexity explanations:**

this algorithm uses [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), where a 'digit' is actually a character, and is O(n), and using it will **prevent the O(nlogn)** for other sort algorithm or using a TreeSet

we iterate over the array which is at most of size n (if every country appears only once).

a trick point is the sort inside a loop: it is still O(n) because at overall you sort at most n elements (and not n elements per iteration!) so it is O(2n)=O(n).

we can pre-find the NumberOfElements with a single iteration.

at overall: it is **O(n*S)**, where n is the number of inputs (where populating arr), and S is the biggest string size (since we need to read the strings...)

Answer (score 1):

A [java.util.Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) should get you on track.

Comment: Fully agree, after filling the Map, you can receive Entries from the Map and sort them as you want

Comment: sorting is O(nlogn).and as he said, this is what he had tried, and he didn't pass the interview

Comment: @amit, agreed, my comment was made before the edit of the question which provided this information.

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient way in terms of coding time would be to forget Java and use `sort | uniq -c | sort -n` (which is, incidentally, one of my favorite shell snippets).  Follow that with `awk` if you really need the formatting as depicted.  The runtime won't even be that bad for large inputs (since those are fairly efficient programs) but startup time would dominate on your example list.  Of course you could run it somewhere on the order of 10,000 times before you could launch Eclipse.